# jQuery - Get all elements in body font sizes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to get all the elements, and put them into an array, I have this following code:

```
var elements = $("*");

                console.log(elements);

                $.each(elements, function(){

                        if($.inArray({element: $(this), orginalSize:$(this).css("font-size"), size:$(this).css("font-size")}, fontSizeArray) !== -1)
                        {

                                fontSizeArray.push({element: $(this), orginalSize:$(this).css("font-size"), size:$(this).css("font-size")});
                        }

                });

                console.log(fontSizeArray);
```

But I have a few problems here:

1. $("*") get all elements even in header, so I have meta tags and stuff that doesn't need to be there, so I am trying to get all the elements inside the body.
2. my condition to see if the item exists in the array is also not working, when I have this code in place, fontSizeArray is empty, if I remove the if condition, my array gets populated.
3. Inside my array I am trying to get the element name, be that div, p, a or whatever and assign it to element: but using $(this) is not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if` statement? Each item in the iteration is unique so how could it already be in the array?

Comment: `var elements = $(body).find("*");` solves #1 and instead of `$.each(elements` try: `elements.each(`

Comment: awesome $("body").find("*"); really helped, put it in an answer and ill accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. How to find elements just within body?

You can use [**jQuery find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method off a selection of the body to accomplish this:

```
$('body').find('*');
```

#### 2. Other Issues?

So, ultimately the code as you have it isn't really "filtering" out anything in your call to `$.inArray(...)` because **the jQuery object for each element of the DOM will be unique.**

I've taken a stab at the issue assuming you you want to store the "tag name" of the item *(e.g. DIV, H2, H3, etc)*. I don't believe jQuery [**$.inArray()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) works with objects *(or... I can't get it to work on my machine)* so I simplified using the [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method which will accomplish what you are looking to do:

```
var elements = $("body").find("*"),
    fontSizeArray = [];

elements.each(function() {
    var obj = {
            element: $(this).prop('tagName'),
            originalSize: $(this).css("font-size"),
            size: $(this).css("font-size")
        };
    if (!fontSizeArray.some(function(item) {
            return item.element === obj.element &&
                item.originalSize === obj.originalSize &&
                item.size === obj.size;
        })) {
        fontSizeArray.push(obj);
    }
});

console.log(fontSizeArray);
```